# RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for Generator: size mismatch for weights and biases using Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

I'm training a 3D-GAN to generate MRI volumes. I defined my model as follows:

```
###### Definition of the generator ######

class Generator(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, ngpu):
    #super() makes Generator a subclass of nn.Module, so that it inherites all the methods of nn.Module
    super(Generator, self).__init__()
    self.ngpu = ngpu
    #we can use Sequential() since the output of one layer is the input of the next one
    self.main = nn.Sequential(   
        # input is latent vector z, going into a convolution 
        nn.ConvTranspose3d(nz, ngf * 8, 4, stride=2, padding=0, bias=True), # try to put kernel = (batch_size,4,4,4,512)
        nn.BatchNorm3d(ngf * 8),
        nn.ReLU(True), #True means that it does the operation inplace, default is False

        nn.ConvTranspose3d(ngf * 8, ngf * 4, 4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=True), # try to put kernel = (batch_size,8,8,8,256)
        nn.BatchNorm3d(ngf * 4),
        nn.ReLU(True),

        nn.ConvTranspose3d(ngf * 4, ngf * 2, 4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=True), # try to put kernel = (batch_size,16,16,16,128)
        nn.BatchNorm3d(ngf * 2),
        nn.ReLU(True),

        nn.ConvTranspose3d( ngf * 2, ngf, 4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=True), # try to put kernel = (batch_size,32,32,32,64)
        nn.BatchNorm3d(ngf),
        nn.ReLU(True),

        nn.ConvTranspose3d(ngf, nc, 4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=True), # try to put kernel = (batch_size,64,64,64,1)
        nn.Sigmoid()

        )

  def forward(self, x):
    return self.main(x)


###### Definition of the Discriminator ######

class Discriminator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, ngpu):
        super(Discriminator, self).__init__()
        self.ngpu = ngpu
        self.main = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv3d(nc, ndf, 4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=True),
            nn.BatchNorm3d(ndf),
            nn.LeakyReLU(leak_value, inplace=True),

            nn.Conv3d(ndf, ndf * 2, 4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=True),
            nn.BatchNorm3d(ndf * 2),
            nn.LeakyReLU(leak_value, inplace=True),

            nn.Conv3d(ndf * 2, ndf * 4, 4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=True),
            nn.BatchNorm3d(ndf * 4),
            nn.LeakyReLU(leak_value, inplace=True),

            nn.Conv3d(ndf * 4, ndf * 8, 4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=True),
            nn.BatchNorm3d(ndf * 8),
            nn.LeakyReLU(leak_value, inplace=True),

            nn.Conv3d(ndf * 8, nc, 4, stride=1, padding=0, bias=True),
            nn.Sigmoid()
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.main(x)
```

I then train the model and save it. When loading the model for evaluation and testing I get the following error:

> RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for Generator:
>       size mismatch for main.0.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([64, 1, 4, 4, 4]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([200, 512, 4, 4, 4]).
>       size mismatch for main.0.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([64]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([512]).
>       size mismatch for main.1.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([64]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([512]).
>       size mismatch for main.1.running_mean: copying a param with shape torch.Size([64]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([512]).
>       size mismatch for main.1.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([64]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([512]).
>       size mismatch for main.1.running_var: copying a param with shape torch.Size([64]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([512]).
>       size mismatch for main.3.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([128, 64, 4, 4, 4]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([512, 256, 4, 4, 4]).
>       size mismatch for main.3.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([128]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([256]).
>       size mismatch for main.4.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([128]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([256]).
>       size mismatch for main.4.running_mean: copying a param with shape torch.Size([128]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([256]).
>       size mismatch for main.4.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([128]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([256]).
>       size mismatch for main.4.running_var: copying a param with shape torch.Size([128]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([256]).
>       size mismatch for main.6.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([256]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([128]).
>       size mismatch for main.7.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([256]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([128]).
>       size mismatch for main.7.running_mean: copying a param with shape torch.Size([256]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([128]).
>       size mismatch for main.7.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([256]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([128]).
>       size mismatch for main.7.running_var: copying a param with shape torch.Size([256]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([128]).
>       size mismatch for main.9.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512, 256, 4, 4, 4]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([128, 64, 4, 4, 4]).
>       size mismatch for main.9.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([64]).
>       size mismatch for main.10.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([64]).
>       size mismatch for main.10.running_mean: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([64]).
>       size mismatch for main.10.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([64]).
>       size mismatch for main.10.running_var: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([64]).
>       size mismatch for main.12.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([1, 512, 4, 4, 4]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([64, 1, 4, 4, 4]).

What I'm I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same code to create your model from your class both times? Because the error suggests that the evaluation time model is different from the training time one. You might have to show more of your code for anyone to identify the issue.

Answer (score 3):

The model you loaded and the target model is not identical, so the error raise to inform about mismatches of size, layers, check again your code, or your saved model may not be saved properly

Comment: this is correct. If you changed the weight sizes and biases in you model between training and evaluation, this could happen. If this is wanted behavior though, you can also use the `strict=False` flag when loading the `state_dict` to only load matching weights in the dictionary that you supplied.